# what is the purpose of Binsor when there are c# APIs for Windsor?

Tags: c#, castle-windsor, binsor

I am fairly new to Windsor, and completely new to Binsor, and Boo. However, I am not new to IoC containers.

I have already done several non-trivial things with Windsor. It has all been done in C#, and the XML configuration file syntax is totally foreign to me.

I just recently moved over to a project using Binsor and Boo. I'm having a hard time seeing any additional benefit from using Binsor over the C# APIs provided by Windsor. Does Binsor offer other capabilities that the Windsor C# API does not? Or, is it just so you can configure Windsor using Boo because you like to use Boo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some info on Binsor's advantages, particularly in comparison to XML:

- http://ayende.com/blog/1687/introducting-binsor-the-boo-dsl-for-windsor
- http://ayende.com/blog/2898/binsor-2-0

> Maybe DSL is taking it a bit too much, though. It is a single class that has some fancy sticks in it, and a lot of Boo magic

Looking at the age of those posts, Binsor doesn't seem to be the newest project on the block.  I assume that some of the techniques in Binsor (if introduced there) have since been applied to the Windsor Fluent Registration API as well:

http://docs.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=Fluent-Registration-API&NS=Windsor

I would assume by default that since Boo is a less popular language that the Binsor API is less frequently updated.

I suggest checking into whether Binsor is still updated.  If it isn't, I'd ditch it in favor of the general .Net API.  If it is still updated, I'd take a good look at both options.  Binsor has a potential to have better Boo support, since the Fluent Registration API was designed with C# as the top priority.

*Disclaimer*: I am not directly involved with the Castle.Windsor or Binsor projects, and I have only skimmed the Boo documentation a few times out of curiosity.  Most of this info I've gathered from some minor Windsor experience (with the Fluent Registration API) and from Google - I'm making a lot of assumptions.

Comment: I practically live on that blog these days. We not only use windsor and binsor, but rhino mocks, rhino service bus, and several of the other castle projects. The lack of documentation on those items is overwhelming.

Comment: Binsor was created long before the current Windsor API. AFAIK it's no longer maintained.

Comment: @CharlesLambert : Binsor, Rhino Mocks, Rhino Service bus are **not** Castle projects.

Comment: @MauricioScheffer - I know, we are using *the other castle projects* in addition to those(e.g. Binder). Ayende blogs about all of that stuff.